# Jenkins container is not getting connecting to remote using ssh?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have two docker container one with Jenkins and one is remote container. I want to Run a Jenkins job on remote container.

For that I have given the private keys in credentials, but still connection is **not successful**.

I am able to ping remote container using Jenkins container also I am able to `ssh` to remote container using Jenkins container.

See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: as i know to be able to run a job in a the remote container you should have before a jenkins agent installed on it

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting with remote host ?? Can you please share the ssh command ?
Can you please share output of below command from your Jenkins container :

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

There might be possibility that Jenkins container is able to connect using IP but not using the host_name. Try updating the the /etc/hosts file with remote container host name and then connect.
eg: `172.0.0.1  remote_host local_host`

Also If you have used port forwarding, then you can simply connect with base server IP and different ports assigned to those containers.

Comment: I am able to connect thru ssh in Jenkins container using ssh remote_user@remote_host command to my remote container. but I m not able to add this to Jenkins ssh sites